# Postgresql strange Index sizes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, b-tree

I have a table with ~8M records, with different types of fields b-tree indexed.
by investigating index sizes, i found two strange things:
1- all index sizes are almost the same, regardless of field type (boolean, string, integer)
2 - all of them are much bigger than my expectation, e.g. for a boolean field, even after reindexing, the size is 217MB, so each record takes ~27 bytes.

could some one shed some light on this please? or refer any user oriented documentation about index size estimations

Comment: Please check: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111603/how-does-postgres-make-its-b-tree-index

Answer (score -1):

[This page](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/11/11/discovering-the-computer-science-behind-postgres-indexes) explains how Postgresql's b-tree implemented. [Here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/nbtree/README) is readme from Postgresql developers.

[image: btree page]